# creating dynamic rich:dropdownmenu

Tags: jsf, richfaces

```
MethodExpression methodExpression =  
     application.getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression( 
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(),  
         "#{PrismBacking.onItemClick}",  
         null,  
         new Class[] { ActionEvent.class }); 
menuItem.setActionExpression(methodExpression);
```

I created a dynamic drop down as above my creating action listener but the listener was not called. I included the method inside the getter of dropdown in backing bean. Do I have to configure the action listener in any of the config files. kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do RichFaces, so it may behave different, but with "plain" JSF you'll at least have to set a fixed ID on the `UICommand` component manually.

```
menuItem.setId("someFixedId");
```

Also ensure that the method behind `"#{PrismBacking.onItemClick}"` has exactly this signature:

```
public void onItemClick(ActionEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

Although that should otherwise have produced a pretty self-explaining exception.